# SAPUI5 - dynamic host url datasource

Tags: cordova, sapui5, datasource, manifest.json

I am trying to build a cordova mobile app that will be deployed for different host url (or SAP servers).

I am using an OData service and was able to access the OData that was created with SAP Netweaver Gateway Service Builder. I want to change the host url based on a user input.

Here is the part on my manifest.json where I declare the datasource:

```
"dataSources": {
  "Main": {
    "uri": "http://myhosturl/sap/opu/odata/sap/mymainservice/",
    "type": "OData",
    "settings":{
        "odataVersion": "2.0",
        "useBatch" : true
    }
  }
}
```

and my declaration of models:

```
"MainService": {
    "dataSource": "Main",
    "settings": {
      "synchronizationMode" : "None",
      "defaultBindingMode": "TwoWay",
      "serviceUrlParams": {
        "sap-client": ""
      },
      "metadataUrlParams": {
        "sap-client": ""
      }
    }
  }
```

I successfully made the sap client to be dynamic using the method getManifestEntry(). Is there a way to also change the host url at run time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API docs](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/overview) you can instantiate the `ODataModel` with a `serviceUrl` and `mParameters` map.

So in your use-case if the app is able to start without loading a default model (declared in your `manifest.json`) you could load the OData model inside of your controller and manipulate the `serviceUrl` from your user input before.